# std::initializer_list destructs the containing objects before the scope end in clang

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, clang, initializer-list

As shown in the following code, std::initializer_list's containing objects get destroyed even before the scope finishes. I would like to know whether the code is not complying with the standard or it is a bug in clang (as it works just fine with gcc and vc).

```
#include <iostream>

class Attrib
{
public:
    Attrib()
    {
        std::cout<< "Constructor called"<< std::endl;
    }

    Attrib(const Attrib& r)
    {
        std::cout<< "Copy constructor called"<< std::endl;
    }

    ~Attrib()
    {
        std::cout<< "Destructor called"<< std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto attribs = std::initializer_list<Attrib>({Attrib()});
    std::cout<< "Before returning from main"<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Output in clang is](https://rextester.com/GQQ46264),

```
Constructor called
Destructor called
Before returning from main
```

[Output in gcc is,](https://rextester.com/WVLBN11775)

```
Constructor called
Before returning from main
Destructor called
```

EDIT:
If we modify the initializer_list creation line in main by a bit like this,

```
     std::initializer_list<Attrib> attribs = {Attrib()};
```

[Output in CLang is,](https://rextester.com/RUIB90254)

```
Constructor called
Before returning from main
Destructor called
```

Comment: Are you assuming `std::initializer_list` does a deep copy in it's copy constructor? It does not.

Comment: I haven't read the standard on it but someone told me you can assume the list arguments are essentially `const T&`. So not guaranteed to stay alive past the one line they're used on.

Comment: @ZanLynx, Firstly, the type is const T, but not const T&. Secondly, According to cppreference.com "The underlying array is not guaranteed to exist after the lifetime of the original initializer list object has ended." So it should be valid in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Clang. Possibly [31636](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=31636) or [40562](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=40562).

```
auto attribs = std::initializer_list<Attrib>({Attrib()});
```

This is copy-initializing `attribs` from the initializer `std::initializer_list<Attrib>({Attrib()})`. Following **C++17 guaranteed copy elision**, this is equivalent to copy-initializing `attribs` from `{Attrib()}`.

> [[dcl.init.list]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.list#5)
>
> ¶5 An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation generated and materialized a prvalue of type "array of *N* `const E`", where *N* is the number of elements in the initializer list. Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list, and the `std::initializer_list<E>` object is constructed to refer to that array.
>
> ¶6 The array has the same lifetime as any other temporary object, except that initializing an `initializer_list` object from the array **extends the lifetime** of the array exactly like binding a reference to a temporary.

According to [CWG1565](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html#1565):

> Q. If an `initializer_list` object is copied and the copy is elided, is the lifetime of the underlying array object extended?
>
> A. The consensus of CWG was that **the behavior should be the same, regardless of whether the copy is elided or not.**

As you observed in your EDIT, Clang behaves correctly when we remove the redundant "copy":

```
auto attribs = std::initializer_list<Attrib>{Attrib()};
```

Answer (score -1):

The bug is in your program. `std::initializer_list` are not required to perform a deep-copy on it's assignment operator, it is a light-weight proxy object.

As a result, semantically your `Attrib` objects are destructed immediately after the line `auto attribs = std::initializer_list...` ends (when their temporaries are destroyed). So `clang` is semantically correct.

The reason why gcc gives you a different output is most likely due to different optimizations enabled.

Comment: I did not assume that it would create deep copies. Standard says that (until C++14) the underlying storage to be valid throughout the original initializer_list object's lifetime. Hence it should keep the containing objects valid somehow (despite the underlying storage is unspecified.

If you aren't sure about this, let's change the line to 
std::initializer_list<Attrib> attribs = {Attrib()};
and see what happens, https://rextester.com/RUIB90254